# Pythonでpsutilがインストールできません

Tags: python, python3, jupyter-notebook

Python初心者です。
Pythonをインストール後に「pip install psutil」でインストールをしようとしても写真のようなエラーが出てしまいます。jupyter notebookやmojimojiをインストールしようとした際も同様です。
Pythonのバージョンは3.10.8です。
何か解決方法があればご教示いただけると幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 文字で表示された情報は、画面キャプチャではなく文字のまま質問に貼り付けてください。 (質問は後からでも編集できます)

Comment: まあおそらくこの記事が該当するでしょう。[python pip実行時に「error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with “Build Tools for Visual Studio”」が発生した場合の対処法](https://mebee.info/2020/07/18/post-13597/) 記事はVS2019ですが、今はフルセットのVisual Studio Community 2022か、Build Tools for Visual Studio 2022 をインストールすれば良いと思われます。[Build Tools for Visual Studio 2022（ビルドツール for Visual Studio 2022）のインストール（Windows 上）](https://www.kkaneko.jp/tools/win/buildtool2022.html), [Windows 10 に Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 をインストールしてみる](https://e-kamo.net/install-visual-studio-build-tools-2022-on-sandbox)

Comment: teratail のコメント欄で解決済みのようです。 https://teratail.com/questions/1457852r2s2evw

Answer (score 0):

python -m pip install psutil --user

と入力してみてはいかがですか？